# ui5: unable to highlight a region on map

Tags: sapui5

my code:-

```
jQuery.sap.require( "sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap");
    var oMap = new sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap({
            width:"100%",
            height: '100%',
            plugin: false,
            regions: {
                template: new sap.ui.vbm.Region({
                    code: 'NA',
                    color: '#fff',
                })
            } 
        });
        return new sap.m.Page({
            title: "Maps",
            content: [oMap]
        });
```

I am trying to highlight a region on the map, but may be I am not following the API properly, any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have the corresponding geojson files on the gateway system ? You can check the network tab if the json is being loaded, the url will look something like this : /sap/bc/vbi/geojson/L0.json

Comment: I don't have geojson file, how to create/get it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the GeoJSON files for your region for them to be shown on the Map. The GeoJSON files are searched in the below places, in the given sequence as mentioned [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap.html).

1. server:port/sap/bc/vbi/geojson/L0.json
2. ./media/analyticmap/L0.json

You will have to upload a GeoJSON file in the MIME repository on your gateway system. You can find many sources for GeoJSON on the Internet.

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

http://www.gadm.org/country

However many of these sources will provide you with ShapeFiles. These contain geospatial vector data for defining regions on a map.
You will have to convert your shapefiles to geojson with GDAL or if you use QGIS(like me), GDAL will also installed alongside.

GDAL: http://www.gdal.org/

QGIS: http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

You can run the below commands to converting a Shape File to GeoJSON

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" target.json source.shp
```

Or if you would also like to define CRS

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:4326 target.json source.shp
```

You can create your own regions, using this [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0)

Once you have your GeoJSON file, you can add them to the MIME repository or you can provide a path in your application to the target GeoJSON

```
sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap.GeoJSONURL = "/model/GeoJSON.json";

        var oMap = new sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap({
            width:"100%",
            height: '100%',
            plugin: false,
            regions: {
                template: new Region({
                    code: 'NA',
                    color: 'rgba(184,225,245,1.0)',
                })
            } 
        });
```

You can also refer to this [article](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SVE/How+to+setup+the+content+used+in+SAP+Visual+Business+analytic+choropleth+map).